# using jsf page in portal

Tags: jsf, portal

I am getting the error below when click on any button on my page with is inside a portlet. Why is this happening?

```
[8/27/10 17:45:08:847 IST] 00000051 Servlet       E com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet handleException EJPEJ0069E: URL parsing problem, URL=http://localhost.us.deloitte.com:10040/wps/myportal/!ut/p/c5/fY3JCoMwFEU_6T1sNOlSo6gQjWOr2Yh0QqnDQizN11dwbe9dnjuAgs1ju3avdummsX1DBcpqJCc5FSZBGVDE0HYtFmcOom_CFSokTd6zOfouldB8LXqdYlR4uOj0E-kbxuckuV-y0rF56TMuto76u2rsnPt2QKhAZCEnGBJHZoYnt-Rp53ggGyEOpuEBNSh6-MIIFFBzmId19p5u-gOy-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.
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.util.ViewStructure.createComponent(ViewStructure.java:91)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.util.ViewStructure.restoreStructure(ViewStructure.java:126)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.util.ViewStructure.restoreStructure(ViewStructure.java:128)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.util.ViewStructure.restoreStructure(ViewStructure.java:128)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.restoreViewState(FacesPortlet.java:782)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.restoreViewState(FacesPortlet.java:795)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.restoreView(FacesPortlet.java:1173)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doRender(FacesPortlet.java:365)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doView(FacesPortlet.java:413)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.assignmentinitrequestportlet.AssignmentInitRequestPortlet.doView(AssignmentInitRequestPortlet.java:44)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doDispatch(FacesPortlet.java:301)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:128)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.propertybroker.standard.filter.C2APortletFilter.doFilter(C2APortletFilter.java:183)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:573)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:114)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doRender(PortletServletCollaborator.java:68)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doRender(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:123)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doRender(CacheCollaborator.java:92)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doRender(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:156)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:273)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaborator.java:124)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:121)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:667 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1087)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:118)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:837)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:680)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:588)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:524)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:639)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:235)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:78)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:58)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:74)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.render(PortletInvokerImpl.java:97)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:119)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:80)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.ExtCollaborator.doRender(ExtCollaborator.java:71)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doRender(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:66)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:89)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$2.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:100)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:246)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl$1.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:92)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:175)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:90)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:116)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.doRenderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:641)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.pe.ext.render.AbstractRenderManager.performService(AbstractRenderManager.java:264)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:132)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.extension.render.PortletFragmentRenderer.render(PortletFragmentRenderer.java:218)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.extension.render.PortletFragmentRenderer.render(PortletFragmentRenderer.java:166)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPFragmentRenderPhase.processRendering(WPFragmentRenderPhase.java:248)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPFragmentRenderPhase.processRendering(WPFragmentRenderPhase.java:186)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPBaseRenderPhase.execute(WPBaseRenderPhase.java:194)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractRenderPhase.next(AbstractRenderPhase.java:106)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPAbstractRenderPhase.next(WPAbstractRenderPhase.java:97)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:860)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:617)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:888)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:1257)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:648)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:93)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1248)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1087)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:352)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:88)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:94)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:837)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:680)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:588)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:524)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3517)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:818)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:125)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:677 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:687 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
[8/27/10 17:45:08:687 IST] 00000051 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at
  com.ibm.faces.portlet.util.ViewStructure.createComponent(ViewStructure.java:91)
```

After rendering a page, JSF stores the view state. When you submit a button, the lifecycle restores this view. In your case, this is failing.

I suspect this is due to some `ClassLoader` and/or library configuration issue. Be careful where you put any jar containing a `META-INF/faces-config.xml` file and (the same applies to the portlet bridge library). The location of these files must be consistent with the `ClassLoader` configuration of the application and its core JSF library. If you're deploying from a Rational Application Developer workspace project, check your WAR/EAR project configurations.

As a general rule, I would place JSF libraries into my WARs and nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mcdowell,
i changed the war class loader policy to application from module in my Deployment Descriptor. but initially it used to work with the module option as well. we were unable to indentify what files were changed which has caused this. some files may have been modified and checked in to our version control system by some one and after taking the latest we started getting this issue.

Thanks,
Tejas